# Angular Jasmine/Karma basic Test Spec

Tags: angularjs, karma-jasmine

So this is an odd one, I have setup a seed app and I have created a basic test script on a controller and it works, but then I move to a second one and it gives me the undefined message I am seeing all over the internet , here is the code for both , since I am new to karma-jasmine someone might see what I am missing in my test

First test, (This one works)

```
//Controller

'use strict';

angular.module('myApp',[])// jshint ignore:line

    .controller('HelloWorldController', ['$scope', function($scope) {
        $scope.greeting = 'Hello World!';
    }]);







    //Test Script ***********************************************************

describe('Hello World example ', function() {

    beforeEach(module('myApp'));

        var HelloWorldController,
        scope;

        beforeEach(inject(function ($rootScope, $controller) {
            scope = $rootScope.$new();
            HelloWorldController = $controller('HelloWorldController', {
                $scope: scope
            });
        }));


        it('says hello world!', function () {
            expect(scope.greeting).toEqual("Hello World!");
        });

});
```

This one however does not work

```
// About Controller
'use strict';

angular.module('myApp.module.controller.about', ['ngRoute'])// jshint ignore:line


    .config(['$routeProvider', function($routeProvider) {
      $routeProvider.when('/about', {
            controller: 'aboutController',
            templateUrl: 'com/modules/about/views/about.html',
            hideMenus: true,
            protectedArea: false,
            title: 'About',
            description: '',
            keywords: ''
      });
    }])


    .controller('aboutController', ['$scope', function($scope) {
        $scope.greeting = 'This is the about message!';
    }]);





//Test Script *****************************************

describe('AboutController Test', function() {

    beforeEach(module('myApp.module.controller.about'));

        var aboutController,
        scope;

        beforeEach(inject(function ($rootScope, $controller) {
            scope = $rootScope.$new();
            aboutController = $controller('aboutController', {
                $scope: scope
            });
        }));


        it('about greeting says "This is the about message!"', function () {
            expect(scope.greeting).toEqual("This is the about message!");
        });

});
```

Here is what I am getting from Karma

```
[12:58:47] Starting 'karma'...
INFO [karma]: Karma v0.12.37 server started at http://localhost:9876/
INFO [launcher]: Starting browser PhantomJS
INFO [PhantomJS 1.9.8 (Mac OS X 0.0.0)]: Connected on socket I1XiLeRfz1SiV-wY2Y5x with id 89911408
PhantomJS 1.9.8 (Mac OS X 0.0.0) AboutController Test about greeting says "This is the about message!" FAILED
    Error: [$injector:modulerr] http://errors.angularjs.org/1.4.3/$injector/modulerr?p0=myApp.module.controller.about&p1=Error%3A%20%5B%24injector%3Amodulerr%5D%20http%3A%2F%2Ferrors.angularjs.org%2F1.4.3%2F%24injector%2Fmodulerr%3Fp0%3DngRoute%26p1%3DError%253A%2520%255B%2524injector%253Anomod%255D%2520http%253A%252F%252Ferrors.angularjs.org%252F1.4.3%252F%2524injector%252Fnomod%253Fp0%253DngRoute%250A%2520%2520%2520%2520at%2520http%253A%252F%252Flocalhost%253A9876%252Fabsolute%252Fwebdev%252FE21%252Fsrc%252Flib%252Fjs%252Fangular%252Fangular.min.js%253F54ede95d02e505e15087f0b61af505f27ee25156%253A25%250A%2520%2520%2520%2520at%2520a%2520(http%253A%252F%252Flocalhost%253A9876%252Fabsolute%252Fwebdev%252FE21%252Fsrc%252Flib%252Fjs%252Fangular%252Fangular.min.js%253F54ede95d02e505e15087f0b61af505f27ee25156%253A24)%250A%2520%2520%2520%2520at%2520http%253A%252F%252Flocalhost%253A9876%252Fabsolute%252Fwebdev%252FE21%252Fsrc%252Flib%252Fjs%252Fangular%252Fangular.min.js%253F54ede95d02e505e15087f0b61af505f27ee25156%253A26%250A%2520%2520%2520%2520at%2520http%253A%252F%252Flocalhost%253A9876%252Fabsolute%252Fwebdev%252FE21%252Fsrc%252Flib%252Fjs%252Fangular%252Fangular.min.js%253F54ede95d02e505e15087f0b61af505f27ee25156%253A38%250A%2520%2520%2520%2520at%2520m%2520(http%253A%252F%252Flocalhost%253A9876%252Fabsolute%252Fwebdev%252FE21%252Fsrc%252Flib%252Fjs%252Fangular%252Fangular.min.js%253F54ede95d02e505e15087f0b61af505f27ee25156%253A8)%250A%2520%2520%2520%2520at%2520g%2520(http%253A%252F%252Flocalhost%253A9876%252Fabsolute%252Fwebdev%252FE21%252Fsrc%252Flib%252Fjs%252Fangular%252Fangular.min.js%253F54ede95d02e505e15087f0b61af505f27ee25156%253A39)%250A%2520%2520%2520%2520at%2520http%253A%252F%252Flocalhost%253A9876%252Fabsolute%252Fwebdev%252FE21%252Fsrc%252Flib%252Fjs%252Fangular%252Fangular.min.js%253F54ede95d02e505e15087f0b61af505f27ee25156%253A38%250A%2520%2520%2520%2520at%2520m%2520(http%253A%252F%252Flocalhost%253A9876%252Fabsolute%252Fwebdev%252FE21%252Fsrc%252Flib%252Fjs%252Fangular%252Fangular.min.js%253F54ede95d02e505e15087f0b61af505f27ee25156%253A8)%250A%2520%2520%2520%2520at%2520g%2520(http%253A%252F%252Flocalhost%253A9876%252Fabsolute%252Fwebdev%252FE21%252Fsrc%252Flib%252Fjs%252Fangular%252Fangular.min.js%253F54ede95d02e505e15087f0b61af505f27ee25156%253A39)%250A%2520%2520%2520%2520at%2520eb%2520(http%253A%252F%252Flocalhost%253A9876%252Fabsolute%252Fwebdev%252FE21%252Fsrc%252Flib%252Fjs%252Fangular%252Fangular.min.js%253F54ede95d02e505e15087f0b61af505f27ee25156%253A41)%250A%2520%2520%2520%2520at%2520workFn%2520(http%253A%252F%252Flocalhost%253A9876%252Fabsolute%252Fwebdev%252FE21%252Fsrc%252Flib%252Fjs%252Fangular%252Fangular-mocks.js%253F7822c97bd61398189431d2e3db4e01ed8f9d4f10%253A2391)%250A%2520%2520%2520%2520at%2520attemptSync%2520(http%253A%252F%252Flocalhost%253A9876%252Fbase%252Fnode_modules%252Fjasmine-core%252Flib%252Fjasmine-core%252Fjasmine.js%253F578a1e5ff14db21b04e2d6db7fd0eda37042440c%253A1789)%250A%2520%2520%2520%2520at%2520http%253A%252F%252Flocalhost%253A9876%252Fbase%252Fnode_modules%252Fjasmine-core%252Flib%252Fjasmine-core%252Fjasmine.js%253F578a1e5ff14db21b04e2d6db7fd0eda37042440c%253A1777%250A%2520%2520%2520%2520at%2520http%253A%252F%252Flocalhost%253A9876%252Fbase%252Fnode_modules%252Fjasmine-core%252Flib%252Fjasmine-core%252Fjasmine.js%253F578a1e5ff14db21b04e2d6db7fd0eda37042440c%253A1762%250A%2520%2520%2520%2520at%2520http%253A%252F%252Flocalhost%253A9876%252Fbase%252Fnode_modules%252Fjasmine-core%252Flib%252Fjasmine-core%252Fjasmine.js%253F578a1e5ff14db21b04e2d6db7fd0eda37042440c%253A627%250A%2520%2520%2520%2520at%2520http%253A%252F%252Flocalhost%253A9876%252Fbase%252Fnode_modules%252Fjasmine-core%252Flib%252Fjasmine-core%252Fjasmine.js%253F578a1e5ff14db21b04e2d6db7fd0eda37042440c%253A357%250A%2520%2520%2520%2520at%2520http%253A%252F%252Flocalhost%253A9876%252Fbase%252Fnode_modules%252Fjasmine-core%252Flib%252Fjasmine-core%252Fjasmine.js%253F578a1e5ff14db21b04e2d6db7fd0eda37042440c%253A2360%250A%2520%2520%2520%2520at%2520attemptAsync%2520(http%253A%252F%252Flocalhost%253A9876%252Fbase%252Fnode_modules%252Fjasmine-core%252Flib%252Fjasmine-core%252Fjasmine.js%253F578a1e5ff14db21b04e2d6db7fd0eda37042440c%253A1819)%250A%2520%2520%2520%2520at%2520http%253A%252F%252Flocalhost%253A9876%252Fbase%252Fnode_modules%252Fjasmine-core%252Flib%252Fjasmine-core%252Fjasmine.js%253F578a1e5ff14db21b04e2d6db7fd0eda37042440c%253A1774%250A%2520%2520%2520%2520at%2520http%253A%252F%252Flocalhost%253A9876%252Fbase%252Fnode_modules%252Fjasmine-core%252Flib%252Fjasmine-core%252Fjasmine.js%253F578a1e5ff14db21b04e2d6db7fd0eda37042440c%253A1762%250A%2520%2520%2520%2520at%2520http%253A%252F%252Flocalhost%253A9876%252Fbase%252Fnode_modules%252Fjasmine-core%252Flib%252Fjasmine-core%252Fjasmine.js%253F578a1e5ff14db21b04e2d6db7fd0eda37042440c%253A627%250A%2520%2520%2520%2520at%2520http%253A%252F%252Flocalhost%253A9876%252Fbase%252Fnode_modules%252Fjasmine-core%252Flib%252Fjasmine-core%252Fjasmine.js%253F578a1e5ff14db21b04e2d6db7fd0eda37042440c%253A2354%250A%2520%2520%2520%2520at%2520attemptAsync%2520(http%253A%252F%252Flocalhost%253A9876%252Fbase%252Fnode_modules%252Fjasmine-core%252Flib%252Fjasmine-core%252Fjasmine.js%253F578a1e5ff14db21b04e2d6db7fd0eda37042440c%253A1819)%250A%2520%2520%2520%2520at%2520http%253A%252F%252Flocalhost%253A9876%252Fbase%252Fnode_modules%252Fjasmine-core%252Flib%252Fjasmine-core%252Fjasmine.js%253F578a1e5ff14db21b04e2d6db7fd0eda37042440c%253A1774%250A%2520%2520%2520%2520at%2520http%253A%252F%252Flocalhost%253A9876%252Fbase%252Fnode_modules%252Fjasmine-core%252Flib%252Fjasmine-core%252Fjasmine.js%253F578a1e5ff14db21b04e2d6db7fd0eda37042440c%253A1762%250A%2520%2520%2520%2520at%2520http%253A%252F%252Flocalhost%253A9876%252Fbase%252Fnode_modules%252Fjasmine-core%252Flib%252Fjasmine-core%252Fjasmine.js%253F578a1e5ff14db21b04e2d6db7fd0eda37042440c%253A627%250A%2520%2520%2520%2520at%2520http%253A%252F%252Flocalhost%253A9876%252Fbase%252Fnode_modules%252Fjasmine-core%252Flib%252Fjasmine-core%252Fjasmine.js%253F578a1e5ff14db21b04e2d6db7fd0eda37042440c%253A2215%250A%2520%2520%2520%2520at%2520http%253A%252F%252Flocalhost%253A9876%252Fbase%252Fnode_modules%252Fjasmine-core%252Flib%252Fjasmine-core%252Fjasmine.js%253F578a1e5ff14db21b04e2d6db7fd0eda37042440c%253A678%250A%2520%2520%2520%2520at%2520http%253A%252F%252Flocalhost%253A9876%252Fbase%252Fnode_modules%252Fkarma-jasmine%252Flib%252Fadapter.js%253F3030709c83121e1b2ca4d1e657306b834fc13350%253A318%250A%2520%2520%2520%2520at%2520http%253A%252F%252Flocalhost%253A9876%252Fkarma.js%253A182%250A%2520%2520%2520%2520at%2520http%253A%252F%252Flocalhost%253A9876%252Fcontext.html%253A75%0A%20%20%20%20at%20http%3A%2F%2Flocalhost%3A9876%2Fabsolute%2Fwebdev%2FE21%2Fsrc%2Flib%2Fjs%2Fangular%2Fangular.min.js%3F54ede95d02e505e15087f0b61af505f27ee25156%3A39%0A%20%20%20%20at%20m%20(http%3A%2F%2Flocalhost%3A9876%2Fabsolute%2Fwebdev%2FE21%2Fsrc%2Flib%2Fjs%2Fangular%2Fangular.min.js%3F54ede95d02e505e15087f0b61af505f27ee25156%3A8)%0A%20%20%20%20at%20g%20(http%3A%2F%2Flocalhost%3A9876%2Fabsolute%2Fwebdev%2FE21%2Fsrc%2Flib%2Fjs%2Fangular%2Fangular.min.js%3F54ede95d02e505e15087f0b61af505f27ee25156%3A39)%0A%20%20%20%20at%20http%3A%2F%2Flocalhost%3A9876%2Fabsolute%2Fwebdev%2FE21%2Fsrc%2Flib%2Fjs%2Fangular%2Fangular.min.js%3F54ede95d02e505e15087f0b61af505f27ee25156%3A38%0A%20%20%20%20at%20m%20(http%3A%2F%2Flocalhost%3A9876%2Fabsolute%2Fwebdev%2FE21%2Fsrc%2Flib%2Fjs%2Fangular%2Fangular.min.js%3F54ede95d02e505e15087f0b61af505f27ee25156%3A8)%0A%20%20%20%20at%20g%20(http%3A%2F%2Flocalhost%3A9876%2Fabsolute%2Fwebdev%2FE21%2Fsrc%2Flib%2Fjs%2Fangular%2Fangular.min.js%3F54ede95d02e505e15087f0b61af505f27ee25156%3A39)%0A%20%20%20%20at%20eb%20(http%3A%2F%2Flocalhost%3A9876%2Fabsolute%2Fwebdev%2FE21%2Fsrc%2Flib%2Fjs%2Fangular%2Fangular.min.js%3F54ede95d02e505e15087f0b61af505f27ee25156%3A41)%0A%20%20%20%20at%20workFn%20(http%3A%2F%2Flocalhost%3A9876%2Fabsolute%2Fwebdev%2FE21%2Fsrc%2Flib%2Fjs%2Fangular%2Fangular-mocks.js%3F7822c97bd61398189431d2e3db4e01ed8f9d4f10%3A2391)%0A%20%20%20%20at%20attemptSync%20(http%3A%2F%2Flocalhost%3A9876%2Fbase%2Fnode_modules%2Fjasmine-core%2Flib%2Fjasmine-core%2Fjasmine.js%3F578a1e5ff14db21b04e2d6db7fd0eda37042440c%3A1789)%0A%20%20%20%20at%20http%3A%2F%2Flocalhost%3A9876%2Fbase%2Fnode_modules%2Fjasmine-core%2Flib%2Fjasmine-core%2Fjasmine.js%3F578a1e5ff14db21b04e2d6db7fd0eda37042440c%3A1777%0A%20%20%20%20at%20http%3A%2F%2Flocalhost%3A9876%2Fbase%2Fnode_modules%2Fjasmine-core%2Flib%2Fjasmine-core%2Fjasmine.js%3F578a1e5ff14db21b04e2d6db7fd0eda37042440c%3A1762%0A%20%20%20%20at%20http%3A%2F%2Flocalhost%3A9876%2Fbase%2Fnode_modules%2Fjasmine-core%2Flib%2Fjasmine-core%2Fjasmine.js%3F578a1e5ff14db21b04e2d6db7fd0eda37042440c%3A627%0A%20%20%20%20at%20http%3A%2F%2Flocalhost%3A9876%2Fbase%2Fnode_modules%2Fjasmine-core%2Flib%2Fjasmine-core%2Fjasmine.js%3F578a1e5ff14db21b04e2d6db7fd0eda37042440c%3A357%0A%20%20%20%20at%20http%3A%2F%2Flocalhost%3A9876%2Fbase%2Fnode_modules%2Fjasmine-core%2Flib%2Fjasmine-core%2Fjasmine.js%3F578a1e5ff14db21b04e2d6db7fd0eda37042440c%3A2360%0A%20%20%20%20at%20attemptAsync%20(http%3A%2F%2Flocalhost%3A9876%2Fbase%2Fnode_modules%2Fjasmine-core%2Flib%2Fjasmine-core%2Fjasmine.js%3F578a1e5ff14db21b04e2d6db7fd0eda37042440c%3A1819)%0A%20%20%20%20at%20http%3A%2F%2Flocalhost%3A9876%2Fbase%2Fnode_modules%2Fjasmine-core%2Flib%2Fjasmine-core%2Fjasmine.js%3F578a1e5ff14db21b04e2d6db7fd0eda37042440c%3A1774%0A%20%20%20%20at%20http%3A%2F%2Flocalhost%3A9876%2Fbase%2Fnode_modules%2Fjasmine-core%2Flib%2Fjasmine-core%2Fjasmine.js%3F578a1e5ff14db21b04e2d6db7fd0eda37042440c%3A1762%0A%20%20%20%20at%20http%3A%2F%2Flocalhost%3A9876%2Fbase%2Fnode_modules%2Fjasmine-core%2Flib%2Fjasmine-core%2Fjasmine.js%3F578a1e5ff14db21b04e2d6db7fd0eda37042440c%3A627%0A%20%20%20%20at%20http%3A%2F%2Flocalhost%3A9876%2Fbase%2Fnode_modules%2Fjasmine-core%2Flib%2Fjasmine-core%2Fjasmine.js%3F578a1e5ff14db21b04e2d6db7fd0eda37042440c%3A2354%0A%20%20%20%20at%20attemptAsync%20(http%3A%2F%2Flocalhost%3A9876%2Fbase%2Fnode_modules%2Fjasmine-core%2Flib%2Fjasmine-core%2Fjasmine.js%3F578a1e5ff14db21b04e2d6db7fd0eda37042440c%3A1819)%0A%20%20%20%20at%20http%3A%2F%2Flocalhost%3A9876%2Fbase%2Fnode_modules%2Fjasmine-core%2Flib%2Fjasmine-core%2Fjasmine.js%3F578a1e5ff14db21b04e2d6db7fd0eda37042440c%3A1774%0A%20%20%20%20at%20http%3A%2F%2Flocalhost%3A9876%2Fbase%2Fnode_modules%2Fjasmine-core%2Flib%2Fjasmine-core%2Fjasmine.js%3F578a1e5ff14db21b04e2d6db7fd0eda37042440c%3A1762%0A%20%20%20%20at%20http%3A%2F%2Flocalhost%3A9876%2Fbase%2Fnode_modules%2Fjasmine-core%2Flib%2Fjasmine-core%2Fjasmine.js%3F578a1e5ff14db21b04e2d6db7fd0eda37042440c%3A627%0A%20%20%20%20at%20http%3A%2F%2Flocalhost%3A9876%2Fbase%2Fnode_modules%2Fjasmine-core%2Flib%2Fjasmine-core%2Fjasmine.js%3F578a1e5ff14db21b04e2d6db7fd0eda37042440c%3A2215%0A%20%20%20%20at%20http%3A%2F%2Flocalhost%3A9876%2Fbase%2Fnode_modules%2Fjasmine-core%2Flib%2Fjasmine-core%2Fjasmine.js%3F578a1e5ff14db21b04e2d6db7fd0eda37042440c%3A678%0A%20%20%20%20at%20http%3A%2F%2Flocalhost%3A9876%2Fbase%2Fnode_modules%2Fkarma-jasmine%2Flib%2Fadapter.js%3F3030709c83121e1b2ca4d1e657306b834fc13350%3A318%0A%20%20%20%20at%20http%3A%2F%2Flocalhost%3A9876%2Fkarma.js%3A182%0A%20%20%20%20at%20http%3A%2F%2Flocalhost%3A9876%2Fcontext.html%3A75
        at /webdev/E21/src/lib/js/angular/angular.min.js:39
        at m (/webdev/E21/src/lib/js/angular/angular.min.js:8)
        at g (/webdev/E21/src/lib/js/angular/angular.min.js:39)
        at eb (/webdev/E21/src/lib/js/angular/angular.min.js:41)
        at workFn (/webdev/E21/src/lib/js/angular/angular-mocks.js:2391)
    TypeError: 'undefined' is not an object (evaluating 'scope.greeting')
        at /webdev/E21/src/com/modules/about/aboutController_spec.js:17
PhantomJS 1.9.8 (Mac OS X 0.0.0): Executed 1 of 2 (1 FAILED) (0 secs / 0.007 secPhantomJS 1.9.8 (Mac OS X 0.0.0): Executed 2 of 2 (1 FAILED) (0 secs / 0.01 secsPhantomJS 1.9.8 (Mac OS X 0.0.0): Executed 2 of 2 (1 FAILED) (0.004 secs / 0.01 secs)
```

Someone who has more familiarity with this might see what I am missing, since I know the first test works I know my setup is correct so the issue must lie in the actual test spec for the about controller, any help would be appreciated .

Answer (score 0):

After playing around with it , I found this to be a bit deceptive the issue wasn't in the specs at all, the specs worked, the issue was in the karma conf file, I had included the angular-mocks but nothing else once I expanded my bower_components from just mocks to a few others I was able to get all the test to run and complete without issue.

Here is what I included for those having a similar problem , (This is under the files area on the karma.conf file)

```
'bower_components/angular/angular.js',
        'bower_components/angular-route/angular-route.js',
        'bower_components/angular-mocks/angular-mocks.js',
        'bower_components/angular-resource/angular-resource.js',
        'bower_components/angular-cookies/angular-cookies.js',
        'bower_components/angular-sanitize/angular-sanitize.js',
        '../src/com/**/*.js',
        '../src/com/**/*_spec.js'
```